# Getting a 400 error when using OAuth

Tags: oauth2, php

Exception: https://login.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/token: curl= (OK); http=400 (Bad Request)

I am getting this error when a few users are trying to use my page. But other users are fine.
Is there an OAuth configuration at the profile level that I am missing?

Comment: were you able to fix this, or at least, understand what is going on? I am having the same issue now; authentication works for most of my users, but some are getting a 400 as well.

Comment: Look at the body of the 400 response - is there any detail there?

Comment: The response body is None